# Save file location on upload

Tags: php, post, upload

I am having trouble uploading a file in PHP. I need to save a file's location in a db, but it won't work. Also, I want to rename the file to be equal to a timestamp + the user's name. I have the users name stored in a variable.

Most importantly though, how do I post the file's location to the DB?

### EDIT

Right now, I'm getting the file to upload to a folder on the server, but what I can't do is save the file's location as a string on the db. I want to be able to reference the file later, but don't know how to save the file's location for later use.

```
$ext_img_2 = end(explode(".", $_FILES["img_2"]["name"]));
if ((($_FILES["img_2"]["type"] == "image/gif") || ($_FILES["img_2"]["type"] == "image/jpeg") || ($_FILES["img_2"]["type"] == "image/png") || ($_FILES["img_2"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg")) && ($_FILES["img_2"]["size"] < 6291456) && in_array($ext_img_2, $allowedExts))
{
    if ($_FILES["img_2"]["error"] > 0)
    {
        echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["img_2"]["error"] . "<br>";
    }
    else
    {
        if (file_exists("AdImg2/" . $_FILES["img_2"]["name"]))
        {
            echo $_FILES["img_2"]["name"] . " already exists. " . "<br>";
        }
        else
        {
            move_uploaded_file($_FILES["img_2"]["tmp_name"], "AdImg2/" . $_FILES["img_2"]["name"]);
            mysql_query("INSERT INTO data (img_2) VALUES ('AdImg1/".$_FILES['img_1']['name']."')";
            echo "Stored in: " . "AdImg2/" . $_FILES["img_2"]["name"] . "<br>";
        }
    }
}
else
{
    echo "Invalid File" . "<br>";
}
```

Comment: Saving the file's original location on the client computer is no longer possible in any modern browser for security reasons.

You'll get `C:/Fakepath` instead of the original path. 
This may be possible to circumvent with the HTML 5 file API (not sure) but you'd have to rebuild your entire uploading process for that

Comment: @Pekka웃 does he not just want to store the file location on the server and then store that in a db?

Comment: @Tom ah, maybe you're right. In that case you need to add more detail, copilot. What fails where, what happens?

Comment: I just added the problem under the edit. Please help. Also, I'm sorry for not adding more detail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend you to use unique name for uploaded file (with function like uniqid http://php.net/manual/fr/function.uniqid.php ) and use original file extention if needed. 
For example :

```
$name = uniqid() . '.' . pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
$name = time() . '.' . pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION); // For timestamp
```

Then, you perform tour tests and do :

```
$path = 'uploadedFilesDir/' . $name;
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["img_2"]["tmp_name"], $path);
mysql_query('INSERT INTO data(...) VALUES ("' . $path . '")');
```

Simple as that (pay attention to directory rights, php may not be able to write in a directory).